# sd card doesn`t have old apps?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, micro-sd

I recently bought a bigger SD card since my old one began to get full. I did what was the most logical: copied all the folders through a PC.

After I put it in the Phone, the card got recognized, the thing is there was nothing in "app/Games" or "music" only in "pictures" and "other".

Then after having to wait like 30 mins to get to the "start screen", I saw that there were nearly no apps on the screens! Nearly all of my folders were deleted/had weird and wrong apps/names (I think the names and Apps part is actually thanks to the newest windows 10 update) So when I checked all my apps I saw that about 50% of them had no picture and couldn't be put on the "start screen" so I thought "OK why not re-download some of these and see if I still got process on some of the games!" but to no suprise days.- no weeks of progress in some apps was lost + all my Music.

After I searched on the Internet, someone said to save the old data on the phone, than put in the new sd and save it on that. I put in my old sd and OF COURSE everything is gone (again in "other")

I also heard that it's because its encrypted for security reasons but I think that:

1. that's stupid and
2. Microsoft needs a function to transfer data from sd cards otherwise I'm really considering switching I hope I can still get help for this problem!

OH and for some reason with every update my background picture changes to a dumb feather and with this one it just got English WTH!? (it was German before)

Comment: You should be able to download the apps again to your new card - are you seeing an error that is stopping you?

Answer (score 2):

To answer you, its not possible. And as a app developer I am happy that Microsoft made this "stupid" decision else if anyone would have bought my app and downloaded on SD card - this could have been then distributed leaving me unhappy about lost income.

Comment: The problem would be solved for both if before installing those apps in the new phone it checks the MSFT Account.

Comment: To go into technical details, the apps needs to be encrypted locally with a key which is in the Phone. Once the phone is formatted or changed, you do not have the same key hence its impossible to do this.